# MacBook Pro not booting

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, hardware, battery, magsafe

I have a mid 2010 MacBook Pro that won't boot up. Faced this problem quite a while ago, so i sent it in for repair and was told the logic board may need replacement. The store told me they tested my machine out with a working logic board and replacing it would solve the issue.

I decided not to get it fixed and took it home.

Strangely enough, I was able to boot up after I left the store. There was around 20% charge on it too, seemed to work fine. I was not able to get the battery to charge though, MagSafe light would remain green. Eventually the battery drained since it couldn't charge.

I even replaced the MagSafe DC-in board myself later but it doesn't charge no matter what, light remains green.

My question is, if my logic board was truly faulty, would it have been possible to boot up when I got it back from the store?

**Edit**: I have tried the following:

- Asking a friend of mine to verify if my MagSafe adaptor works and was told there was no issue with charging.
- Disconnecting the battery and plugging in the MagSafe adaptor to boot up, which didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, if my logic board was truly faulty, would it have been
>   possible to boot up when I got it back from the store?

**Because, not everything is absolute.**

In other words, you may have an intermittent failure of some component.  I't possible it's a failing capacitor, resistor or even IC (Integrated Circuit, aka "chip").   There may be dry (broken or otherwise faulty) solder joints.  You may even have electrical "glue" that has become dry/cracked and is contributing to the intermittent functionality.

Without putting "hands on" it would be impossible to accurately diagnose and/or repair.  However, IMO, unless you can source a replacement logic board on the cheap, fixing an almost 9 year old machine is going to be cost prohibitive.